# NHibernate holding on to a reference to data objects

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, memory

I'm trying to work out where a lot of the memory in my app is going and while doing some profiling I'm noticing that any data objects that are loaded by NHibernate are hanging around once the request (is asp.net), and therefore session, has ended.  Tracing it back, there are various things that seem to be doing it, like the "SingleTableEntityPersister" and the "StatefulPersistenceContext".  I've disabled 2nd level caching for now, but they're still being held on to

Any ideas?

The session is being correctly disposed:

```
        if (session != null)
        {
            if (session.Transaction != null && session.Transaction.IsActive)
            {
                session.Transaction.Rollback();
            }
            else
            {
                session.Flush();
            }

            session.Close();
            session.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: How are you cleaning up your session after the request is completed?

Comment: Have edited the question

Comment: @Paul and who's keeping the session alive?

Comment: The SessionFactory is holding on to the objects, the Session is nowhere to be seen

Comment: I'm fairly certain objects in the first level cache are limited in scope to the session.  It sounds like you are leaking sessions, but hard to say from the information you've provided.  When you say "data objects" do you mean actual entities retrieved, or DB metadata?

Comment: I don't seem to have any leaked sessions, they all seem to have been closed and disposed.  I may try and write a small console app and see if I can replicate the issue.  "Data objects" are the actual entities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHibernate tracks all changes that are made to objects, that means that if you do:

```
user.FirstName = "name"
```

it will make the appropriate update in the DB.

But to track this NH needs references to all your objects. To get not tracked entities you can either use `IStatelessSession` or remove object from the session using the `Evict` method.

When session is disposed it releases all the tracked entities. So check if session is deleted properly and transaction is closed

Comment: I've edited the question to show the end of the session - it's being closed and disposed.